# How to call a plugin function in footer.php

Tags: plugins, functions, footer

I want to call this http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-media-gallery/ 
easy media gallery plugin in footer.php or recommend me any image gallery plugin like its in the footer of this website http://ssmrudrapur.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing the plugin and adding images to a new gallery, paste this code into your footer.php file where you want the gallery to display

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[easy-media med="231,233"]'); ?>
```

Simply change the gallery i.d's to your own as the ones in the code above are examples.

**No Need To Use A Plugin**

I also suggest you use the native WordPress gallery which enables you to set both the size of the thumbnail images (Settings > Media) and the amount of columns.

You can also hook these in from your child themes functions.php file rather then add the shortcode to the footer.php template which isn't best practice.

Sample code (Tested)

```
function wpsites_footer_gallery() {

echo '<div class="footer-gallery">';
echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="11" link="file" ids="37468,37566,37466,37467,37423,37462,37388,37417,37421,37422,529" orderby="rand"]');
echo '</div>';
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'wpsites_footer_gallery');
```

Position using the .footer-gallery class.

Change the wp_footer hook to your theme specific hook (If it includes hooks)

Here's the result using the code above:

[image]

Comment: In easy media gallery plugin, they have put the limitation of only 3 columns. I want to remove this limitation and add as many as I need the columns. Kindly tell me the solution code how to do this. Thanx in advance

Comment: Brad answered your original question. If it is the answer you should accept it. If you have more questions, you will need to ask them separately.

Comment: @helgatheviking I'll definitely check Brad's ans as accepted ans, Don't worry about it, my next ques is connected with the previous one, i.e. why I commented it.

Comment: Good to hear. Also, please try to put more info into the question next time. Users shouldn't have to click to 2 other sites to figure out what you are asking. You are also required to show some research effort, by explaining what have you tried, etc.

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes Madam !!!

Comment: @Brad Found the solution of the commented ques, Thanx for solution of previous question.