# I want to add a gallery to a post but I don't want it displayed in the content?

Tags: gallery

I want my user to able to add a gallery to a post and then run a conditional like:

```
<? php
if (strpos($post - > post_content, '[gallery') !== false) {
    echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');
} else {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

But using wordpress' stock gallery and adding it to a post also shows the gallery inside the content.

**I have a 2 column layout, the right column has `the_content()` but I want the left column to display the gallery if it has one.**

How do I go about making this work?

Comment: You should be able to adapt this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106403/21376

Comment: Is the left column a sidebar?

Comment: @BradDalton Hi, nope, it's just a content area.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This method enables you to display the native WordPress gallery using the gallery shortcode in a custom function [How to call a plugin function in footer.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129677/how-to-call-a-plugin-function-in-footer-php/129678#129678)

You can use any WordPress or theme specific hook.